# How to center shapes based on Canvas size using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, mvvm

Having a code to display a circle (using an `ellipse` with equal width and height, and also using `reactive ui` for notifications) I want to draw a circle in the middle of the canvas, but also manage resize update.

The current code sets `Canvas Left` and `Canvas Top`, but I am not sure how to set circle in the middle and to fill almost all the canvas.

## classes:

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<IShape> Shapes
    {
        get => _shapes;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _shapes, value);
    }
    private ObservableCollection<IShape> _shapes;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
      //here the location is set, but how to adjust it to the center of canvas?
        Shapes = new ObservableCollection<IShape>
        {
            new Circle {
                Top = 100,
                Left = 100,
                Radius = 50,
                Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 233,222, 0) 
            }                
        };
    }       
}

public interface IShape
{
    int Top { get; set; }
    int Left { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Shape : ReactiveObject, IShape
{
    private int _top;
    private int _left;

    public int Top
    {
        get { return _top; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _top, value); }
    }

    public int Left
    {
        get { return _left; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _left, value); }
    }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    private int _radius;
    private Color _color;

    public int Radius
    {
        get => _radius;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _radius, value);
    }

    public System.Windows.Media.Color Color
    {
        get => _color;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _color, value);
    }
}
```

## xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Shapes}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>           
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:Circle}">
                <Ellipse Width="{Binding Radius}" 
                         Height="{Binding Radius}"
                         Canvas.Top="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         Canvas.Left="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         >
                    <Ellipse.Stroke>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
                    </Ellipse.Stroke>
                </Ellipse>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Top, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Left, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

this produces:

[image]

How May I change the **xaml** or **code behind** to center and set the circle almost as the size as canvas like?:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your elipse almost as big as the canvas by binding the elipse size to the canvas size and using a converter that will convert the input values to (for example) 0,9 times the size of the canvas like so:

XAML

```html
            <Canvas Name="MyCanvas">
            <Ellipse Height="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource MyScaleConverter}}" Width="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource MyScaleConverter}}"></Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
```

C#

```
    public class ScaleZeroNine : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDouble(value) * 0.9;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Regarding the center issue:
Why are you even using a canvas? is there a specific reason for it? Canvas makes using WPFs full power difficult as its arrangement is more like winForms. When using for example a grid it will center automatically and can also be defined to do so

Comment: Nice answer Denis, I want to make thing using MVVM, so What would be the best aproach to initialize all shapes at center of screen, by just adding a grid like:

´defining grid definitions like:  <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                                               <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
  
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ...> 

</Grid>´  would sufice, or how to init all elements at center?

Comment: not sure if i really understand your question at this point...
but if you really want to go the easy route and avoid the converter you could do it like this:


<Grid Width="50" Height="50">
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="Black" Height="1"/>
    <Rectangle Width="1" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Ellipse Margin="5" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
</Grid>

This is not the most ellegant way but maybe it helps...
If not please try to as in a defferent way

Comment: *ask
Generally  it makes sense not to define the size of the grid so the entire control stays scalable as soon as you change the window size..
MVVM has absolutly nothing to do with this sepcific layout..are you sure you do understand the concept of MVVM?

Comment: Well, the question is how to init objects created at view model, I mean, to create them at the center of screen for example, this is because, on MainViewModel()i add the shapes like:
        Shapes = new ObservableCollection<IShape>
        {...}

Comment: Okay when using the MVVM Pattern you get your actual View, for example the MainWindow, its code-behind and the ViewModel.
In the ViewModel you want to have the application code, meaning the actual function of your program. You do not want to modify the GUI directly from here as this would break the MVVM pattern. That also means you do not want to initialize GUI components from here.
What you want to do i guess is have the circle and the lines apeare and hide at run time...

Comment: To do this correctly create the element in your view using XAML and bind its visibility  to a dependencyproperty in your view. Now you can hide and unhide it during runtime.

Comment: If you hovever decide you dont want to go the MVVM route and want to create these elements during runtime you will need an instance of the class you are trying to add an element to. If it is the MainWindow its pretty easy you cand do the following:
                Ellipse eli = new Ellipse();
                eli.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                eli.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                eli.StrokeThickness = 1;
                (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).YourGridNameHere.Children.Add(eli);

Answer (score 0):

Give the ellipse a render transform:

```
<Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Yellow" Stroke="CornflowerBlue" StrokeThickness="                    
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="-25" Y="-25" /> <!-- center the ellipse -->
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: Don`t complete understand, How could I make Width and Height variable and let them be for example almost the area of canvas? Maybe binding a canvas property or somthing similar

Answer (score 0):

To complement answer I used multi-binding with a custom value converter.

```
public class HalfValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values,
                          Type targetType,
                          object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "HalfValueConverter expects 2 double values to be passed" +
                " in this order -> totalWidth, width",
                "values");
        }

        double totalWidth = (double)values[0];
        double width = (double)values[1];
        return (object)((totalWidth - width) / 2);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value,
                                Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter,
                                CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

then in xaml

```
 <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <local:HalfValueConverter x:Key="HalfValue" />
        </DockPanel.Resources>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
            <Ellipse 
                     Height="{Binding ElementName=canvas, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource Escalated}}" 
                Width="{Binding ElementName=canvas, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource Escalated}}"
                     Stroke="Red"
                     x:Name="ellipse">
                <Canvas.Left>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HalfValue}">
                        <Binding ElementName="canvas" Path="ActualWidth" />
                        <Binding ElementName="ellipse" Path="ActualWidth" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Canvas.Left>
                <Canvas.Top>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HalfValue}">
                        <Binding ElementName="canvas" Path="ActualHeight" />
                        <Binding ElementName="ellipse" Path="ActualHeight" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Canvas.Top>
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
```